# Changing path names to linked files in a Word document with over 100 linked text files

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want in a Word document with over 100 linked text files to change the path name in the text file link.
I copied a macro that exactly should do what I want to have done but I keep getting an error 91 on the "        .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, oldFilePath, newFilePath)" line. I tried to work around it but I can't find a solution.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

I used a similar kind of code in a Word macro but this gives the same problem.

Below the VBA code I am working with in Excel.

```
Sub UpdateWordLinks()
Dim oldFilePath As String
Dim newFilePath As String
Dim sourceFileName As String
Dim newFileName As String
Dim wrdApp As Object
Dim wrdDocument As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer

'The file name and path of the file to update
sourceFileName = "c:\test.docx"
'The old file path as a string (the text to be replaced)
oldFilePath = "R:\Manuals\"
'The new file path as a string (the text to replace with)
newFilePath = "C:\NL\Manuals\"
'Set the variable to the Word Application
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'Make the Word application visible
wrdApp.Visible = True
'Set the variable to the Word Document
Set wrdDocument = wrdApp.Documents.Open(sourceFileName)
'Use Replace to change the oldFilePath to the newFilePath on the Field code
Counter = wrdDocument.Fields.Count
For i = 1 To Counter
wrdDocument.Fields(i).Open
    With wrdDocument.Fields(i).LinkFormat
        .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, oldFilePath, newFilePath)
    End With
Next i
'Update the links
wrdDocument.Fields.Update
'Save, close and quit the application
wrdDocument.Save
wrdDocument.Close
wrdApp.Quit
'Release the memory
Set wrdApp = Nothing
Set wrdDocument = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at this `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.linkformat.sourcefullname` may need to check the type too

Comment: «may need to check the type too» Not so. What needs to be checked is whether the field has a .LinkFormat property. For example: If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the field has a .LinkFormat property. For example:

```
For i = 1 To Counter
  With wrdDocument.Fields(i)
    If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
      With .LinkFormat
        .SourceFullName = Replace(.SourceFullName, oldFilePath, newFilePath)
      End With
    End If
  End With
Next I
```

Your:

```
wrdDocument.Fields(i).Open
```

line is also likely to cause an error.

If your links use INCLUDETEXT fields, their paths can be modified to auto-update without the need for a macro. See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Comment: Thanks, the linkformat check solved the error 91 problem. The result I wanted to realize is not realized with this. I have in total approx. 100 links to text document in my main Word document but in total over 350 links, so the linkformat check made sense. By adding subdocuments Word adds an Hyperlink to the specific text document. I also tested the link to msofficeforums suggestion but without result. I have the impression that the hyperlinks are not editable, is this correct?

Comment: in above message I ment over 350 fields which have to be checked instead of links.

Comment: «The result I wanted to realize is not realized with this» Well, you need to tell us *exactly* what it is you're trying to achieve that 'is not realized with this'. Hyperlinks are quite editable. You can loop through the hyperlinks collection for that.«I also tested the link to msofficeforums suggestion but without result.» That's too vague for any meaningful comment.

Comment: To be more specific.

Comment: This is what I have:

Comment: R:\Handleidingen\1 NL\Pro MP\Tekstmodules\Handleiding is bedoeld voor NL 03-01-2019.docx
 
R:\Handleidingen\1 NL\Pro MP\Tekstmodules\Optische straling NL 03-01-2019.docx
 
R:\Handleidingen\1 NL\Pro MP\Tekstmodules\UV-lamp typen MD NL 24-01-2019.docx
 
R:\Handleidingen\1 NL\Pro MP\Tekstmodules\UV-desinfectie NL 11-01-2019.docx
This are only 4 lines out of over 100 links to sub-documents. If I look at the link in Word with Alt-F9 they look like this:

Comment: { HYPERLINK "R:\\Handleidingen\\1 NL\\Pro MP\\Tekstmodules\\Handleiding is bedoeld voor NL 03-01-2019.docx" \n }
 
{ HYPERLINK "R:\\Handleidingen\\1 NL\\Pro MP\\Tekstmodules\\Optische straling NL 03-01-2019.docx" \n }
 
{ HYPERLINK "R:\\Handleidingen\\1 NL\\Pro MP\\Tekstmodules\\UV-lamp typen MD NL 24-01-2019.docx" \n }
 
{ HYPERLINK "R:\\Handleidingen\\1 NL\\Pro MP\\Tekstmodules\\UV-desinfectie NL 11-01-2019.docx" \n }

Comment: In these links I want to replace the part "R:\Handleidingen\1 NL\Pro MP\Tekstmodules\" by "C:\Users\rob\International\R&D - Documenten\Handleidingen\Pro MD\1 NL\Tekstmodules NL"

Comment: Sometimes I am able to change the "R:" into "C:", but if I look with Alt-F9 to the hyperlink the "R:" isn't changed. Obviously I only change the name instead of also the address.

Comment: In the loop for each field I am now using: 
wrdDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Address = Replace(wrdDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Address, oldFilePath, newFilePath)

Comment: You could, of course do the whole lot with a single Find/Replace, without ever needing to go anywhere near VBA...

Comment: I started with that but that doesn't work. The Find/Replace function doesn't change hyperlinks.

Comment: Did you press Alt-F9 to expose the document's field codes? Note, too, the need for double backslashes for the path separators when using Find/Replace. Find/Replace won't update the hyperlink display text, however, which is quite independent of where the hyperlink actually points to.

Comment: I use Alt-F9 to see the field codes yes. The double backslashes come automatically with Alt-F9. This has no effect on the Find/Replace action. The Find function doesn't find whatever is in the hyperlink.

Comment: Well, it won't find them if you don't use double backslashes for the path separators when using Find/Replace... The mere fact you see them with the field code display toggled on doesn't change that.